# Visual Studio throws exception: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3'

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

When I launch a Windows Phone 8.1 project in Visual Studio I get this error in the designer :

```
An Exception was thrown.
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
StackTrace
   at SQLite.SQLite3.SetDirectory(UInt32 directoryType, String directoryPath)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
   at com.example.DataAccess.MainRepository.<GetLanguagesForID>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at com.example.View.UserControls.LanguageItem.<awaitResult>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(Object state)
InnerException: None
```

I have added the sqlite for Windows Phone 8.1 via NuGet but I still happen to get this error.
The designer should displays some rows of data from a database but instead shows this error. Yet it displays them fine once the application is running in the simulator, how can I fix this?